# How can I fix "Exception Thrown" error in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, image, visual-studio, opencv, exception

I meet an error while compile my OpenCV program in Visual Studio 2017. The error occurred when I used the function `imwrite` to save a grayscale image. You can see the screenshot here

[image: the screen capture here]

I tried to copy file `opencv_world320.dll` to my directory project but still not ok.

This is the code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argv, char** argc)
{
   Mat img_original = imread("lisa.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
   Mat img_grayscale = imread("lisa.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

   imshow("Lisa-Original", img_original);
   imshow("Lisa-Grayscale", img_grayscale);

   imwrite("LisaGray.jpg", img_grayscale);
   waitKey(0);
   return 0;
}
```

This is the exception:

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FFC7D9B86C2 (opencv_world320.dll) in
>   1_open_image_lisa.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location
>   0x000001926A40F000. occurred

Comment: My first guess, since you use relative paths for input, is that you don't actually read the images. so check if the read was successful by checking the images to have data: _if(img_original.empty()) return -1; //or whatever you may want to do if you don't get the image_

Comment: thanks, but reading the images was successfully. I've just met error with line code imwrite("LisaGray.jpg", img_grayscale) to save an image. Then i check in my project folder, this image was created but its size is 0kb and can't open.

Comment: I noticed you mix the older c and c++ api, try to include highgui.hpp: _#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>_

Answer (score 1):

The code isn't wrong by itself, and even if the imread wasn't successful, the imwrite wouldn't throw. (Although, empty cv::Mat written to jpg file create empty files, which aren't recognize as valid image files).

So, to pinpoint your exact problem, use the try/catch mechanism:

```
try {
    imshow("Lisa-Original", img_original);
    imshow("Lisa-Grayscale", img_grayscale);

    imwrite("LisaGray.jpg", img_grayscale);
}
catch(cv::Exception& e) {
    std::cout << e.msg << std::endl;
}
```

On my computer, when imwrite fail because of the format, the message is:

```
OpenCV(4.0.0) D:\Dev\Opencv4\opencv-4.0.0\opencv-4.0.0\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp:661: error: (-2:Unspecified error) could not find a writer for the specified extension in function 'cv::imwrite_'
```

In this case, try to use another format to save the picture, and/or check if opencv was compiled with the correct options and libraries.

Comment: _catch_ won't actually catch _access violation_

Comment: Arf, indeed yes.

Comment: The advice is good nevertheless, but this particular issue is from something else, won't be fixed with a try/catch

Comment: Still can't work. It shows the same error message.

Exception thrown at 0x00007FFB753786C2 (opencv_world320.dll) in 1_open_image_lisa.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000001A8226D4000. occurred

Comment: @HoàngĐức did you try what i suggested: not mix c and c++ api? //normally that should not be an issue, but it might be some bug that breaks that compatibility

Answer (score 0):

It happen to mine too.  You can use "Release" configuration instead of "DEBUG"'s when you run your C++ code.  It works for me, but do not know why!